# how to solve the failed linking file resources

Tags: android

I am facing the following error:

> C:/Users/ramya/AndroidStudioProjects/clock 
>   app/src/main/res
>   drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml 
>   error: attribute 'android:endX' not found.
>   error: attribute 'android:endY' not found.
>   error: attribute 'android:startX' not found.
>   error: attribute 'android:startY' not found.
>   error: attribute 'android:offset' not found.
>   error: attribute 'android:offset' not found.
>   error: attribute 'android:fillType' not found.
>   error: attribute 'android:fillType' not found.
>   java compiler:
>   failed linking file resources.

Do you have any idea of how I can solve it?

Comment: Please provide content of drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml

Comment: i  provided the content but the error was still there wat can i do..